# Unity Scroll View. Как сделать так, чтобы содержимое скрол вью было всегда сначала

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скроллвью в юнити. В нем разный контент- тексты, слайдеры. Сам скрол вью находится внутри Panel. Панелька вызывается кликом в интерфейсе. Все работает, но когда скрол показывается, то контент показывает с того места, на котором закрыли панель.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии панельки со скроллом весь контент при следующем вызове панели был сначала и его не приходилось бы вручную листать наверх.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому понадобится, нашел для себя одно решение. Я скриптом задал позицию контента в скролл вью

```
 public void resPos()
{
    transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Навесил этот код на контент: Scroll View -> Viewport -> Content.
И на кнопку "закрыть" у панельки со скроллом при клике просто обращаюсь к resPos().